# How to change to code to get an output of a float in a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to get a output of `[3.1]` where the number in the list is a float.

```
b = "3.1"
list1 = []
for i in b:
    list1.append(i)
print(list1)
```

I expect the output to be `[3.1]`, but the code above outputs `['3', '.', '1']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse a string to a float or int in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int-in-python)

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? What does `i` contain in each iteration of your loop?

Comment: You need to cast your string as a float to append it to a list @ProgrammingWarrior check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see what is happening under the hood here

```
In [9]: b = "3.1"                                                                                                                                                                 

In [10]: for i in b: 
    ...:     print(i) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                          
3
.
1
```

As you can see, since `b` is a string, iterating over a string gives you individual characters of the string, which you end up appending to the list, and the list looks like `['3', '.', '1']`

Hence you need to convert the string to a float, and then append it to the list, which is as simple as

```
In [11]: b = "3.1"                                                                                                                                                                

In [12]: [float(b)]                                                                                                                                                               
Out[12]: [3.1]
```

Here we convert b to a float, and create a single list element with `3.1` as it's only element

A similar idea can be applied when you are dealing with a list of strings and each string represents a float, where we convert every element to a float, and make a new list out of it

```
In [13]: b = [ "2.7", "2.9", "3.1"]                                                                                                                                               

In [14]: [float(i) for i in b]                                                                                                                                                    
Out[14]: [2.7, 2.9, 3.1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`for i in b: list1.append(i)` means "for each character in the string `b`, append that character to the list `list1`", giving you exactly what you asked for: a three-character list.

If you just want to turn `b` into float and append to the list, this suffices:

```
list1.append(float(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
list1 = [float(b)]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[3.1]
```

The reason you're getting a list like `['3', '.', '1']` is because you're iterating over all the characters of string `b`. You need to convert the string type of `b` to float and then append it to a list.

Answer (score 0):

In the code, variable b is of format string. Convert it to float and append to list.

```
b = "3.1"
list_1 = []
list_1.append(float(b))
print (list_1)
```

This should give you the desired output.

The way you are doing, variable b is in string format. This makes the for loop append individual character to list that is respectively '3', '.', '1'. Conversion of string to float should solve your problem.